# Mean function using values from double array displaying wrong values

Tags: c

Very new to C, anyways been coding a program where you enter pairs of doubles which are stored in separate arrays. I have created a function to get the mean of the numbers but when I call it inside main the values are different. Any ideas?

MEAN FUNCTION:

```
mean(double *arr)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double meanValue = 0.0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < arr[i]; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        meanValue = sum / i;
    }

    printf("\nmean: %.3lf", meanValue);
}
```

MAIN:

```
double num1[1001];
mean(num1);
```

And, I am getting the num1 and num2 values using:

```
for (k = 0; (scanf_s("%lf,%lf", &num1[k], &num2[k] ) == 2); k++)
```

Comment: `i < arr[i]` makes no sense as a loop condition.

Comment: You need to pass the size of the array to the function, and then use `i < size`.

Comment: And you only need to calculate the `meanValue` once, outside the loop.

Comment: It should be `meanValue = sum / size;`

Comment: @Barmar like sizeof(arr)?

Comment: No, you need to pass `k` to the function, since that's the number of usable elements.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't work for arrays passed into functions, you have to pass the size yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The function needs to know how many of the array elements it should process.

```
mean(double *arr, int size)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double meanValue = 0.0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    meanValue = size > 0 ? sum / size : 0;

    printf("\nmean: %.3lf", meanValue);
}
```

The size is the value of `k` after the input loop is done, so you call it:

```
mean(num1, k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to pieces of information:

- the pointer to the data array;
- the size of the array (number of elements).

However, the way you are computing the mean is subjected to bad numeric conditioning (floating point overflow). Here I suggest using the [Incremental Averaging](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106720) instead. Please consider this code:

```
double mean(double *arr, int num)
{
    double res = arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < num; ++i)
        res += (arr[i] - res) / (i+1.0);

    return res;
}
```

Note that I'm assuming you are using a C99 compliant compiler for the integer declaration inside the for loop.